# node json2csv no output

Tags: json, node.js, csv

Please bear with me I am brand new on the node platform.

json2csv has been installed like so:

```
$ npm install json2csv --save -g
```

trying to recreate the example from the [website](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv#command-line-interface) on the command line.

file: [mycars.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/plo5sx4kq440eil/mycars.json?dl=0)

when running:

```
$ json2csv -i mycars.json -f carModel,price,colors -p
```

it comes back so:

```
---------------------------------
| "carModel" | "price" |"colors"|
---------------------------------    
|            |         |        |
---------------------------------
```

whereas expectation is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| "carModel" | "price" | "colors"                          |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  "Audi"    | 0       | "[""blue"",""green"",""yellow""]" |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  "BMW"     | 15000   | "[""red"",""blue""]"              |
------------------------------------------------------------
(more lines)
```

Do you know what might be going wrong here or have suggestions on how to start debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change this:

```
{
  "mycars": [
    {
    "carModel": "Audi",
    "price": 0,
    "colors": ["blue","green","yellow"]
  }, {
    "carModel": "BMW",
    "price": 15000,
    "colors": ["red","blue"]
  }, {
    "carModel": "Mercedes",
    "price": 20000,
    "colors": "yellow"
  }, {
    "carModel": "Porsche",
    "price": 30000,
    "colors": ["green","teal","aqua"]
  }
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
[
  {
    "carModel": "Audi",
    "price": 0,
    "colors": ["blue","green","yellow"]
  }, {
    "carModel": "BMW",
    "price": 15000,
    "colors": ["red","blue"]
  }, {
    "carModel": "Mercedes",
    "price": 20000,
    "colors": "yellow"
  }, {
    "carModel": "Porsche",
    "price": 30000,
    "colors": ["green","teal","aqua"]
  }
]
```

and use the correct property names. E.g. you don't have `color` in JSON.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the property name mistake - corrected.